# Numpy: Add each row of a matrix to the matrix (one at a time), then find the min for each row in each new matrix. Wish to speed the code up

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

I am adding each row of a matrix, to the matrix, then computing the min of each row in the new matrix.

My current code from python is with a test case is:

```
# Compute distances to all other nodes using landmarks 
distToLM = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
m = len(distToLM)
count = 1
dist = np.zeros((m,m))
for i in range(m):
    findMin = distToLM[i,:] + distToLM.take(range(count,m),axis=0) 
    dist[i,count:]=np.min(findMin,axis = 1)
    count = count + 1
```

Note: I am slicing the matrix each time as I only require the upper triangular values of the matrix

So the first iteration would add [1,2,3] to [4,5,6] and [7,8,9] to make a matrix:

[5,7,9]

[8,10,12]

From here I want the min of each row, so 5 and 8.

Next iteration I would take [4,5,6] and add it to all rows beneath it i.e [7,8,9] and take the min of each row.

This code is rather slow, around 3 seconds for a 4000x4000 matrix.

I've also tried a Cython version, there was not much of a speed increase likely due to the heavy dependence on calling the numpy functions VS executing the main code in C:

```
DTYPE=np.int

ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def findDist(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] distToLM):
    cdef int m = distToLM.shape[0]
    count = 1
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] dist = np.zeros((m,m),dtype=DTYPE)
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] findMin
    for i in range(m):
        findMin = distToLM[i,:] + distToLM.take(range(count,m),axis=0) 
        dist[i,count:]=np.min(findMin,axis = 1)
        count = count + 1
    return dist
```

I assume if there was some way to vectorize this it would be much faster.

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: It would help if you provided a minimal test `distToLM`. I tried to test you code a bit, and gave up.  It's not worth my time to guess.

Comment: When I have a chance tomorrow morning I will put up an example matrix. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing it a bit helps me visualize the action better (I don't use `take` much):

```
distToLM = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
m = distToLM.shape[0]
dist = np.zeros((m,m), distToLM.dtype)
for i in range(m):
    findMin = distToLM[i,:] + distToLM[i+1:,:] 
    dist[i, i+1:] = np.min(findMin,axis = 1)
```

In fact the double iteration is even clear:

```
distToLM = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
m = distToLM.shape[0]
dist = np.zeros((m,m), distToLM.dtype)
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(i+1,m):
        dist[i,j] = np.min(distToLM[i,:] + distToLM[j,:])
```

That reveals a symmetry in the 2 dimensions that is obscured in your code.  It's not faster, but will be easier to implement with Cython memoryviews.

That symmetry also shows that I can perform an 'outer' sum on these rows:

```
In [512]: np.min(distToLM[:,None,:]+distToLM[None,:,:],axis=-1)
Out[512]: 
array([[ 2,  5,  8],
       [ 5,  8, 11],
       [ 8, 11, 14]])
```

The upper tri is the desired dist.

```
In [518]: np.triu(_,k=1)
Out[518]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  8],
       [ 0,  0, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

This calculates more values than the iterative approach, but can be faster.  Unfortunately for your big problem, the intermediate size (4000,4000,4000) array may be too big for memory.

I could pick the `triu` indices before hand with:

```
In [530]: I,J=np.triu_indices(3,1)
In [531]: I,J
Out[531]: (array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int32), array([1, 2, 2], dtype=int32))
In [532]: np.min(distToLM[I,:]+distToLM[J,:],axis=1)
Out[532]: array([ 5,  8, 11])
```

I don't have a feel for how that will perform with large arrays.

This reminds me that `scipy.spatial` has what it calls `squareform` and `compact` representations of pairwise distances.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html

Maybe there's some useful stuff there.